# Understanding currying and HOFs

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, currying

I am currently studying functional programming and it's most important feature : Higher Order Functions.

It's not as crystal clear as I'd like currently and therefore I'd like to understand perfectly how HOFs work.

Considering this function

```
{- Curried addition. -}
plusc :: Num a => a -> (a -> a)
plusc = (+)
```

To what extent can we say that this function uses **currying** and is a HOF ?

EDIT : Basically, I don't understand how the definition of the function stands for an addition (parameters, associativity, etc )

Comment: To full extent? I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, or what part you don't understand.

Comment: Well I don't understand how this function stands for an addition. To what extent does the function definition *defines* an addition.

Comment: The addition is defined by the `+` operator, which `plusc` uses. Maybe it helps to write out `plusc x y = x + y` or `plusc = \x -> \y -> x + y` (which are just syntactic sugar for each other, like `x + y` = `(+) x y`)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't *personally* call `plusc` a HOF, because its arguments aren't functions. A way to spot an obvious HOF is to look for a parens in the signature that *aren't at the leftmost side*:

```
{- equivalent signature -}
plusc :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

When we remove optional parens, it's obvious that the function isn't a HOF that takes functions, but it's curried.

> Note: Since every curried function can *return* a function, though, we might say that after partially applying it, it returns a function, and as such operates on functions - so it is a HOF. I don't think this is particularly helpful way of describing/learning the concept, but I suppose the definition would span both parameters and results.

An uncurried version would simply group its arguments:

```
plusUnc :: Num a => (a, a) -> a
```

Now a HOF might *take* such a function and turn it into some other one:

```
imu :: Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a)
imu f = \a b -> f a b
```

> Note: The lambda impl could obviously be simplified, I spelled it out just for illustration.

Note that `f` is the "lower" order function that's being passed into `imu`. To use it:

```
imuPlus = imu plusc  -- a function is being passed

imuPlus 1 2          -- == 3
```

> Note: since we're mixing both concepts (and you asked for both), `imu` is also curried. An uncurried version could look like this:
>
> `imuUnc :: ((a -> a -> a), (a, a)) -> a`
>
> Now it is a HOF (it has a function in the parameters), but it doesn't return a function, which differs from the examples above.
>   It's just much easier to use when it's curried, though, mostly because of partial application.

Comment: Higher-order can also mean that a function returns another function, which is pretty standard for Haskell's curried functions though

Comment: @Bergi oh well, okay, *returning* a function could perhaps also make a function a HOF; I very rarely look at it that way, but I'll edit it in.

Comment: @Bergi In Haskell, I also rarely think of function-returning functions as HOFs, but I guess that could still fit. I'd probably be more tempted to call `plusc` a HOF because the `Num a =>` constraint is implicitly passing a dictionary containing a bunch of functions to `plusc`. Still, I think that the "HOF" terminology is no longer that useful nowadays -- HOFs have become too common to notice them.